# FireBug and console tab

Tags: firebug

I'm on the console tab but I am not getting any area to write anything. So please guide me how to write something in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Comment: @Thomas: You probably have "LargeCommandLine" turned on, in which case you can type in and execute script code in the right-hand pane of the console.  If you want the regular, one-line command line back, just click the little triangle next to the Console tab head and then, in the pop-up menu, un-check "LargeCommandLine."